# MFMailComposerView attach images

Tags: iphone

how to attach images from iphone saved photo album to MFMailComposerView and send through mail...plese help me..is there any sample application source code available

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say `image` is the image you want to attach.

```
NSData *attachmentData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);

...

MFMailComposeViewController *mailComposer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
...
[mailComposer addAttachmentData:attachmentData mimeType:@"image/jpeg" fileName:@"attachment.jpeg"];
...
// Push it on to the screen.
```

Comment: but,i want to pick the image from saved photo album,and then attach to the mail,,,meanz dynamially...

Comment: I assumed you knew how to get the photos. You will have to use a `UIImagePickerController` instance for getting the photos.

Comment: ohhh,,ok thankz deepak,,but if i mail from mfmailcomposer i didint get the mail ,,

Comment: i just clik the send button and i tAUGHT THE MAIL WAS SEND ,BUT I CHECK THE MAIL NO MAIL COMES IN IT

Comment: Did you implement the delegate? What does it say? What was the result and error?

Comment: @deepak haii deepak,thre is no error message or result,,when i tap the send button in the upper toolbar,nothing happens.i chek the mail,no email comes in it

Comment: Are you using the device? or the simulator? And in case its the device? do you have mail accounts set up on it?

Comment: @deepak,haii deepak,i am using the stimulator not the devicee

Comment: Try this out on an actual device with a mail account setup. It should work there. It is one of those features that you will need device to test on.

Comment: ohhhh ,thanks for giving me sucha a valuable information,i just know one more thing,,i want to share a image through facebook,twitter and by mail.i had done in facebook and mail...but thre is no API found in sharing in twitter..any help

Comment: yeaa, i know share kit,,but the clint dosnt like the interface of the sharekit,,he wants facebook ,twitter ,mail in  diffrent buttons,,.so i put graphapi for facebook ,and with the help of u i finished the mail ,but any way in twitter?

Comment: Have you looked at `MGTwitterEngine`? Its a very popular tool. I haven't used it though.

Comment: Put out a question, I am sure quite a few know about it.